# how can I get my ids products with foreach?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i want to valid one the sale is processed , but my last stock is equal to  x stock then it will be added to notification table , but how can I get my products ids only ids foreach , to after that send them hashed to my get_product

functions to get cart

```
 $this->session->carrito = $this->sale->checar_existe_carrito();
 $array  = $this->sale->get_all_cart($this->session->carrito);
```

json

```
[{"id":"4165","qty":"1.00","price":"77.00","name":"hammer"},{"id":"4168","qty":"3.00","price":"7.00","name":"whey protein"},{"id":"4169","qty":"3.00","price":"500.00","name":"papas"}]
```

function to valid then stock product is equal to x stock

```
public function concretar_venta(){
        if($this->sale->checa_carrito_vacio($this->session->carrito)){
            $total = $this->input->post("total", TRUE);
            $cantidad_pagada = $this->input->post("cantidad_pagada", TRUE);
            $cambio = $cantidad_pagada - $total;
            $producto = $this->products->get_product('861578d797aeb0634f77aff3f488cca2');
            if($this->sale->concretar_venta($this->session->carrito, $total, $cantidad_pagada, $cambio)){
                if($producto->stock <= 2){
                   $this->notification->addNotification('low stock', $product_id[$output], $user_id[$output_u], 'low stock',now());
                }else{
                    echo 'bien';
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "Ocurrio un error al concretar la venta, por favor intentelo de nuevo";
            }
        }
        else{
            "El carrito está vacío";
        }
    }
```

retrieve function tests

```
  public function FunctionName() {
    $json = '[{"id":"4165","qty":"1.00","price":"77.00","name":"hammer"},{"id":"4168","qty":"3.00","price":"7.00","name":"whey protein"},{"id":"4169","qty":"3.00","price":"500.00","name":"papas"}]';

    $jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);

    $ids = array();

    foreach ($jsonArray as $value) {
      $ids[] = md5($value['id']);
    }
      print_r($ids);
      $producto = $this->products->get_product($ids);
    }
```

[image: why_is_sending_array_as_a_column]

Comment: You need to extract the only id's from JSON. Is it?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of the error messages.  It breaks this site's ability to index the page for search.

Answer (score 0):

This solution based on your provided JSON

```
$json = '[{"id":"4165","qty":"1.00","price":"77.00","name":"hammer"},{"id":"4168","qty":"3.00","price":"7.00","name":"whey protein"},{"id":"4169","qty":"3.00","price":"500.00","name":"papas"}]';

$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
// echo '<pre>'; print_r($jsonArray); die; // check what is coming in array

$ids = array();
// extract ids using loop
foreach ($jsonArray as $value) {
  $ids[] = md5($value['id']);
}
// print_r($ids); die;

foreach ($ids as $id) {
  $producto = $this->products->get_product($id);
}
```

You can experience live here [Link](https://3v4l.org/AFmuu)

Comment: yes, but what I wanted to do is why the array when I try to send it $ids it sends the array as a column name and not values

Comment: didn't understand what you are saying?

Comment: @AronImperial answer upadted check it now

Comment: when I want to try to send my md5 string throught ids then says Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

Comment: it says it should be string , but how can I send the dinamic array/

Comment: do this foreach ($ids as $id) {
  $producto = $this->products->get_product($id);
}

Comment: i need $producto = $this->products->get_product(md5(array ids));

Comment: Ah hash your id while adding them in array

Comment: Don't apply  md5 on array

Comment: how can I do it to send all through md5?

Comment: @AronImperial Updated with md5 check now.